# configure maven for both personal and work use

Tags: maven, vpn

At my job we use a nexus server that requires credentials. it is also only available through our network (or VPN). I was provided with a maven settings.xml for this purpose.

I also want to have a more conventional configuration for some side projects of mine, because using the same configuration is very inconvenient, but Im not sure of how to switch configurations without replacing the whole settings.xml every time.

The settings is basically taken from [this example](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html) but with a  entry for credentials. How can I turn off this config and connect to the central maven repo when I'm at home?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well, you seem not to be the first one facing the problem. I've found some discussion on this here: http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Conveniently-switch-between-settings-td126255.html

However I don't think there is fully flexible/automatic solution the one would expect.

As a summary of the discussion, I see 2 options:

- switch the `settings.xml` based on your environment or
- use the `-s` switch for `mvn` command to specify the alternate `settings.xml` file

My experience is that, switching settings.xml based on environment (the 1.st option) does the job for me.

Comment: +1, just to add - you can use the same **~/.m2/repository** directory for both, the maven metadata includes the source repository so each instance can share only what is visible to both (saving disk and bandwidth).

Comment: I will go for this solution, using the alias hmvn (home maven) for the command

Comment: thanks for sharing your way, sounds like an interesting one, maybe I use it in my env as well :) As I'm on Linux I just started to think of alias for mvn that would do the (inteligent) decision internally for me.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is define 2 profiles in your settings XML - one should use the intranet-only repositories, the other - open internet repositories (e.g. Bintray's JCenter). 
Then define one of the profiles active by default, and trigger the usage of the other with `-p` (and disabling the auto-activated with `!`)

[Here's](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) the full profiles reference for you.